# How to change color of v-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

[image]

I'm using Vuetify

```
<v-select id="makeMeBlue" dense outlined :items="form.values.urlTypes" 
          label="Single or Multi URL" v-model="form.values.urlType" 
          :rules="form.rules.urlType">
</v-select>
```

I'm trying to make my download button color blue

- The border
- The text "Download As..."
- The right down arrow

---

I've tried

add this prob `color="blue"` ad add this CSS

```
#makeMeBlue {
  color:blue; 
  border: blue 1px solid; 
}
```

Can someone please give me a hint ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is feasible. Did you checked this one? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite vuetify classes:
(wrapp your select in div)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      form: {values: {urlTypes: [1,2]}}
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#makeMeBlue .v-label {
  color:blue !important;
}
#makeMeBlue .v-icon {
  color: blue !important;
}
#makeMeBlue .v-text-field--outlined fieldset {
  border: blue 1px solid !important; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
      <br />
      <div id="makeMeBlue">
        <v-select dense outlined :items="form.values.urlTypes" label="Download as ..." v-model="form.values.urlType" ></v-select>
      </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly, when I tested with my codes, I see it overwrite so many components. How can we prefix class/id that will only apply to that menu ? to that 3 mini elements ? #makeItBlue ?

Comment: I've tried this, but no luck. https://i.imgur.com/MpwIqXF.png

Comment: @code-8 hey mate, I corrected my answer take a look again pls